# ionic geolocation change marker place

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, geolocation, ionic-framework, marker

I use Ionic geolocation to tracking client place , but the marker does not change her place , please any one can help me ,  this is my controller code:

**Controller**

```
app.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $state, $http, $cordovaGeolocation, $interval, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.positions = [{
        lat: 43.07493,
        lng: -89.381388
    }];
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
        $scope.map = map;
        $scope.positions = [];
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Loading...'
        });
        $scope.map = map;
        var getLocation = function() {
            marker.setVisible(false);
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    'icon': 'img/marker2.png'
                });
                marker.setVisible(true);
                marker.setIcon('http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_gray.png');
                $scope.positions.push({
                    lat: pos.k,
                    lng: pos.B
                });
                console.log(pos);
                $scope.map.setCenter(pos);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
        };
        $interval(getLocation, 5000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring the marker with no position then updating your marker variable using the `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` function provided by cordova instead of using `$interval` which may return same position if the user doesn't move.

This function gets a new position data set when it detects changes. See full usage here [Cordova-Plugin-Geolocation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn9qn3wePKAhWFdCwKHf_nAwAQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fapache%2Fcordova-plugin-geolocation&usg=AFQjCNE-2B0E8h2sczcjs1i4987BB3JL5A&sig2=EWnDg-ANRcOXo5qf-BJH2A&bvm=bv.113370389,d.bGg)

Example:

```
app.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $state, $http, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {
  $scope.positions = [{
    lat: 43.07493,
    lng: -89.381388
  }];
  $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
    $scope.map = map;
    $scope.positions = [];
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...'
    });
    $scope.map = map;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_gray.png',
      map: map,
      visible: false
    });
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      marker.setPosition(pos);
      $scope.positions.push({
        lat: pos.k,
        lng: pos.B
      }); 
      console.log(pos);
      map.setCenter(pos);
      if(!marker.getVisible()) {
        marker.setVisible(true);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }
    });
  });

  ...

});
```